# javascript not reading characters

Tags: php, javascript, string, variables

I'm sure the answer to this is stunningly simple - but I can't find it!

I have a javascript embedded in a PHP (which will return a string value to my android app) and for some reason it will only read the PHP echo'd variable when it contains **all integers**!

I need it to read characters and integers since usernames consist of that.

Looking forward to tips - embarassed I couldn't figure this one out on my own;

Notes on my code: I deactivated the Android function at the end, since the problem occurs before that gets implemented; also set up $myvar = '20' so you can see it works for all integers;

```
<?php  

if (!isset($_SERVER['WEBAUTH_USER'])){
    $login = 'Wrong username';
}else{

$login = $_SERVER['WEBAUTH_USER'];
//$myvar = 'Hello, world';
}

$myvar = $login;

//$myvar = '20';

//echo $myvar;
    ?>


<script type = "text/javascript">
jsvar = <?php echo $myvar;?>;
document.write(jsvar);  
//Android.getValue(jsvar);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're leaving out quotes:

```
jsvar = "<?php echo $myvar; ?>";
```

Of course, there'll be problems if the string contains quotes, so a better solution is to use something like a JSON utility to sanitize the string.

It worked with numeric strings because JavaScript understood those as numeric constants.